# Get input text value, after selected an option (all from a json file), ANGULAR 10

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4

Basically I have this selection with some input fields:

```html
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-lg-6">
   <label>Città*</label>

    <select formControlName='cittaLegale' class="form-control" id="citta_legale" 
      name="citta_legale" required>
           <option value="" disabled selected> Scegli </option>
           <option  *ngFor="let comune of comuni" value="" > {{comune.Comune}}</option>
      </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-lg-4">
    <label>Provincia*</label>

    <input formControlName='provinciaLegale' type="text"  class="form-control" 
        id="provincia_legale" name="provincia_legale"
        placeholder="Es.RM" value='' required maxlength="2" style="text- 
    transform:uppercase" >

</div>
```

So I did a `ngFor` to get all Comune from a JSON file and I need to autocomplete the input `provinciaLegale` (Provincia) based on I choosing the select.

This is my function to get JSON file:

```
listaComuni(){
  this.http.get("assets/it.json").subscribe(data=>{
  this.comuni = data;

})
```

and this is part of the JSON file:

```
    [
     {
     "Istat": "028001",
     "Comune": "Abano Terme",
     "Provincia": "PD",
     "Regione": "VEN",
     "Prefisso": "049",
     "CAP": 35031,
     "CodFisco": "A001",
     "Abitanti": 19726,
      },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to select the option and set it's value to the ProvinciaLegale input?

You could add a valueChanges hook (inside your *ngOnInit()*) to cittaLegale select formControl, like this:

```
this.formGroup.get('cittaLegale').valueChanges.subscribe(newValue => {
    this.formGroup.get('provinciaLegale').setValue(newValue);
});
```

Comment: i tried but when i insert these lines on the ngOnInit(), i can't see anymore the options into my select.